# Echo tld based on current session id codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-variables

**I have a controller**

```
<?php
class Onetimescan extends CI_Controller{
    public function index() {
        #LOAD MODEL
       $this->load->model('scanmodel');
            $this->scanmodel->loadurlbasedonsessid($this->session->userdata('session_id'));      
    }
}
?>
```

**and a model:**

```
<?php
class Scanmodel extends CI_Model{
    function __construct(){
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function loadurlbasedonsessid($sid){
        $sid = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
        $this->db->select('tld');
        $this->db->where('session_id', $sid);
        $q = $this->db->get('ClientDomain');
        $r = $q->result_array();
        echo($r[0]['tld']);
    }   
}
?>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Call to a member function userdata() on a non-object
```

I thought I was properly passing the `session_id` in between the `controller` and `model`, but this isnt the case? Can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the [Session](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) library isn't loaded.

To load it on demand (usually in the controller):

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

or add it to your `application/config/autoload.php`:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Comment: I just caught this myself! Silly me!! Jeez, thanks.